# Is there any predefined function in C++ to find the minimum and maximum element from a given array?

Tags: c++, function, minimum

I have an array

```
double weights[]={203.21, 17.24, 125.32, 96.167}
```

I wish to calculate the minimum and maximum element by using a function if there's any? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is: [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). There's also  [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) for finding just the max and [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) for finding just the min.

---

As applied to your code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

  double weights[]={203.21, 17.24, 125.32, 96.167};

  auto minMaxIterators = std::minmax_element(std::begin(weights), std::end(weights));

  // minMaxIterators is a pair of iterators. To find the actual doubles
  // themselves, we have to separate out the pair and then dereference.
  double minWeight = *(minMaxIterators.first);
  double maxWeight = *(minMaxIterators.second);

  // Alternately, using structured bindings to extract elements from the pair
  auto [minIt, maxIt] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(weights), std::end(weights));
  minWeight = *minIt;
  maxWeight = *maxIt;

  // Alternately, using min_element and max_element separately
  minWeight = *(std::min_element(std::begin(weights), std::end(weights)));
  maxWeight = *(std::max_element(std::begin(weights), std::end(weights)));
}
```

Comment: int minWeight ;
int minWeight = std::max_element (0, sizeOf(minWeight)) ;

Is the the correct way to use it? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Zoori No, not even close. `max_element()` takes a pair of iterators denoting a range of values in a container, and then returns an iterator to the element with the largest value. You need to dereference that iterator to get its value.